# I have a linear layout and a frame layout , i inflate my fragment in the frame layout , How to access the linear layout from the fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout

```
<RelativeLayout
...>
<LinearLayout
...>
<TextView
.../>
</LinearLayout>
<FrameLayout
.../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Inside my main activity:**

I replace my fragment in the frame layout, How to access the linear layout from my fragment class.

**Errors:**

View can be accessed only where it is actually created.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can access any layout in `Activity` from its `Fragment` by using

`Layout yourLayout = (Layout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.idOfLayout);`

Fragments can use the Activity instance with `getActivity()` for something like find a view in the activity layout

Comment: i dont do this - setcontentview(R.id.layout) in my activity, I simply replace my fragment to the frame layout. So can i do this inside my fragment.

Comment: can i use LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.idoflayout); inside my fragment

Comment: If this answer helps you please up-vote and accept my answer. That's how SO works :)